# yahoo music gem not working

Tags: ruby, rubygems, yahoo-api

I want to use yahoo music gem, but I am getting error because of activesupport gem.

my code

```
require 'yahoo-music'
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
Eroor

LoadError: cannot load such file -- activesupport
    from /Users/Ashok/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/Ashok/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/Ashok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/yahoo-music-0.1.0/lib/yahoo-music.rb:1:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/Ashok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/yahoo-music-0.1.0/lib/yahoo-music.rb:1:in `each'
    from /Users/Ashok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/yahoo-music-0.1.0/lib/yahoo-music.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Ashok/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in `require'
    from /Users/Ashok/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/Ashok/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:122:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/Ashok/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

> cannot load such file -- activesupport (LoadError)

https://github.com/mattt/yahoo-music :

```
Additionally, yahoo-music has the following gem dependencies:

* Hpricot >= 0.6
* ActiveSupport >= 2.1.0
* FlexMock >= 0.8.2
```

...which means you have to install those gems too.  Even then you may have to use ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: require 'yahoo-music' gives problem, some ruby is unable to find path.I have edited error in my question